# In Rails using Wicegrid, how do I create link_to to destroy a record and return to the grid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wice-grid

I am using Rails 4 with Wicegrid, I want to have a link on each row of the grid to be able to delete a record, I have created the link_to but when I pressed it I get the error: No route matches [DELETE] "/".

I don't want to send it the user to the a delete view, I want to delete the record and refresh the grid and stay in the grid.

My controller looks like:

```
def destroy
    @risk = current_user.risks.find(params[:id])
     @risk.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to risks_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

My Index view looks like this:

```
<%= 
    grid(@risks_grid) do |g|
       g.column name: 'Id', attribute: 'id'

       g.column name: 'Title', attribute: 'title' do |p|
         p.title if p.title
       end
      .

       g.column do |p|
         link_to("Delete", :back, :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :action => :destroy, :id => p.id, :method => :delete, :class => 'button-xs')                

       end
    end
 %>
```

Thanks,
Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for `link_to` looks a bit off. You're saying that the action is `:back` and then specifying specific parts of another action (`action`, and `id`). I've never used wicegrid but I would think that something like the following would suffice

```
link_to("Delete", p, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, class: 'button-xs')
```

If you want to do the deletion via AJAX so that the user doesn't leave the page you'll need to use `remote: true` in your data attributes:

```
link_to("Delete", p, data: { remote: true, confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, class: 'button-xs')
```

Then in your `destroy.js.coffee` or `destroy.js.erb` you can use jQuery or something similar to make the appropriate updates to the DOM.